# Edit timeout in HttpClient (4.5)

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, final

I need to be able to modify the timeout set in my CloseAbleHttpClient. Here's how I set the different timeouts:

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.copy(RequestConfig.DEFAULT)
            .setConnectTimeout(timeout)
            .setSocketTimeout(timeout)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(managerTimeout)
            .build();

    httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
            .build();
```

Do I have to create a new RequestConfig object, and build the HttpClients.custom() again to achieve this? I have tried this, and the problem arises in that I need my CloseableHttpClient to be final. If I set the timeout 2 times, this isn't possible. I would appreciate any input on how to best modify the timout properties!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing that stops your from using different request config on a per request basis

```
RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(timeout)
        .setSocketTimeout(timeout)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(managerTimeout)
        .build();

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig)
        .build();

RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.copy(defaultRequestConfig)
        .setConnectTimeout(timeout * 2)
        .setSocketTimeout(timeout * 2)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(managerTimeout * 2)
        .build();

HttpGet get = new HttpGet();
get.setConfig(requestConfig);
```

Comment: Can I ask why you call setConfig to 'HttpGet get' and not HttpClient the second time?

Comment: (1) HttpClient instances are immutable, one cannot modify them  (2) one _should_ not modify HttpClient instances in the first place. (3) RequestConfig used by HttpClient represents that defaults that will be used only if individual requests do not provide them. One generally should configure request parameters on HttpUriRequest instances